# How to install pip3 version 3.5?

Tags: python, pip

I've seen a version of pip3.5 installed on a Ubuntu 14.04 but i'm unsure how it was installed as there does not appear to be pip3.5 available.

I've tried :

```
pip3 install --upgrade pip3==3.5
Collecting pip==3.5
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pip==3.5 (from versions: 0.2, 0.2.1, 0.3, 0.3.1, 0.4, 0.5, 0.5.1, 0.6, 0.6.1, 0.6.2, 0.6.3, 0.7, 0.7.1, 0.7.2, 0.8, 0.8.1, 0.8.2, 0.8.3, 1.0, 1.0.1, 1.0.2, 1.1, 1.2, 1.2.1, 1.3, 1.3.1, 1.4, 1.4.1, 1.5, 1.5.1, 1.5.2, 1.5.3, 1.5.4, 1.5.5, 1.5.6, 6.0, 6.0.1, 6.0.2, 6.0.3, 6.0.4, 6.0.5, 6.0.6, 6.0.7, 6.0.8, 6.1.0, 6.1.1, 7.0.0, 7.0.1, 7.0.2, 7.0.3, 7.1.0, 7.1.1, 7.1.2, 8.0.0, 8.0.1, 8.0.2, 8.0.3, 8.1.0, 8.1.1, 8.1.2, 9.0.0, 9.0.1)
No matching distribution found for pip==3.5
```

How to install pip version 3.5 ?

Update :

I installed `numpy` via :

```
pip3 install numpy
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): numpy in /usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages
```

Attempting to use `numpy` in python3.5 causes error :

```
/usr/local/bin/python3.5
Python 3.5.0 (default, Jan 20 2017, 10:14:23)
[GCC 4.8.4] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
>>> import numpy as np
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named 'numpy'
```

But numpy is installed :

```
pip3 install numpy
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): numpy in /usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages
```

I incorrectly assumed that to fix I should update to pip version 3.5 to match python version 3.5 .

So question now is how to install `numpy` to python version 3.5 ?

Comment: Why would you want pip 3.5? The current version is [9.0.1](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pip) (don't confuse with **Python version 3.5**).

Comment: Ubuntu 14.04's package repo contains `pip-1.5.4`, and there has never been a `pip-3.x` version.

Comment: @Aurora0001 please see update

Comment: @birryree please see update

Comment: python 3 bring pip already, if anything use `python3 -m pip ...`

Comment: @Copperfield thanks but does not work : "/usr/local/bin/python3.5 -m pip install numpy
/usr/local/bin/python3.5: No module named pip" also tried : "/usr/local/bin/python3.5 -m pip install numpy
/usr/local/bin/python3.5: No module named pip"

Comment: Sounds more like you have a path issue - why do you have both Python 3.4 and Python 3.5 installed?

Answer (score 4):

Download `get-pip.py` from here https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/installing/

Then with your python interpreter of choice:

```
python3.5 get-pip.py --user
```

Then, by using pip with the `-m` switch you are sure of the interpreter that is used.

```
python3.5 -m pip install --user numpy
```

EDIT: I have a Ubuntu 14.04 desktop at work and had the same issue, no pip found.

Comment: I see you have a `/usr/local` install. If you have appropriate permissions you can drop the `--user` option.